# Setting OSGi import version restrictions dynamically?

Tags: osgi, bundle, equinox

I'm building an OSGi-based web application consisting of just two bundles for now. In one of them, I'm loading process instances from a process engine. Each process instance is supposed to correspond with a specific version of the other bundle, which it was initially assigned to.

For example, I would like to load one process instance in Bundle A and work with it using packages from bundle B in version 1.0. Afterwards, I would get hold of another process instance and work with it using packages from bundle B in version 2.0.

Do you see any way to achieve this functionality?

Thank you very much in advance!
Johannes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bundle A can only be exposed to a single version of a package at any given point. So other than possibly just using reflection, Bundle A cannot use 2 versions of the same package exported by different versions of Bundle B.

Or, do you mean that the 2 versions of Bundle B implement that same package differently. Then Bundle A could see different implementation objects from the 2 versions of Bundle B because they appear to be the same interface type to Bundle A. If this is the case, then OSGi services are the best way for Bundle B to publish these objects for Bundle A to use.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the import and for the advice. With every new version of Bundle B there should be new implementations of the service tasks so I will try providing them for Bundle A using OSGi services. Thanks!